# Problems installing NVIDIA drivers under Fedora: Black screen and errors after reboot

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, fedora

I just switched to Fedora as my main system and I have some issues while installing nvidia drivers on my pc. Basically, I wanted to install nvidia drivers, because I thought that this was my core problem in poor performance in some games. I found several guides(ended using this one: https://itsfoss.com/install-nvidia-drivers-fedora/) on installation process and after several tries it seemed that I installed them correctly, but when I rebooted my pc I had some kind of download and after some time it seemed to switch colors from grey and white to contrast colors like black and orange. After several seconds, pc started and screen was black, so I turned off my pc and booted in other session as I understood.

Here's some more info about system

nvidia-settings:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


(nvidia-settings:3164): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:11:41.933: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:3164): CRITICAL **: 16:11:41.935: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is
       not accessible. This file should have been installed along with this
       driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

neofetch:

```
OS: Fedora Linux 38 (Workstation Edition) x86_64 
Host: MS-7846 0A 
Kernel: 6.5.7-200.fc38.x86_64 
Uptime: 10 mins 
Packages: 2385 (rpm), 13 (flatpak) 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 1280x1024 
DE: GNOME 44.5 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i3-4130 (4) @ 3.400GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 
Memory: 1864MiB / 15923MiB
```

dkms-status:

```
nvidia/545.23.06, 6.5.8-200.fc38.x86_64, x86_64: installed
```

lspci:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] (rev a1)
```

Comment: try an older version of the driver - in the 300s

Comment: @Keltari I installed 390xx. Isn't it part of 300s?

Comment: try an older version.  Ive seen this behavior before and moving to an older version helps.